# How can I force a Windows App to dark mode?

Tags: windows, plugins, darkmode

Some application running on Windows PC doesn't support dark mode, which is annoyed.

Is there any way(including programming or other ways) to force these Apps to dark mode?

Thanks for any hints.
Thanks for any hints.
Thanks for any hints.